# How to say that my grades are the best possible?

Tags: resume

Let's assume that I hold a BSc and an MSc degree.

In the BSc, the marks were 1-10, and I got a GPA of 8.5. So I can easily write on my CV "GPA: 8.5/10".

In the MSc, the grading system was different, and I got on average an A, which is the best grade possible (no A+, A* or similar).

How do I state the information on the CV, that my GPA is the best grade possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List exceptional academic achievements (top grades, published articles, awards, sponsorship) on CV...](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23224/list-exceptional-academic-achievements-top-grades-published-articles-awards)

Comment: I want to share this information, not asking whether I should share it or not. I am looking for wording advice.

Comment: You should question yourself if it's a good idea to point this out. I'm sure 9 out of 10 personnel manager will understand very good marks as very good marks. To point this out could be interpreted as conceited. However, if you want to point it, do it only as a side note and thus, don't worry about that to much, there are other things which are more important.

Answer (score 7):

Assume that the person reading your CV doesn't know the specifics of the qualification.

Is an 85% pass on an exam good or bad?  Put in some detail to help them understand.

Similarly, they probably won't be familiar with your school's MSc marking scheme (especially true if you're applying to foreign institutions).

So, try *explaining* why the grade is so good.  For example:

> BSc.  GPA 85% (3rd in my class)
>
> MSc. Grade "A" (Highest award possible)

Perhaps more important that the actual grade you got, make sure that you explain what you did in the course and why it is relevant for the job.

Comment: >  make sure that you explain what you did in the course and why it is relevant

Answer (score 2):

GPAs are funny business. Folks seem to think that they are super important in applications when, really, depending on the region/culture they're not all that important. Sure you have to make a minimum requirement for many jobs(typically a low B in my field but every field is different) but GPA especially at a graduate level is way over emphasized by many students. In the US, far more important than a numeric value is any achievements, activities, actual work you did.

Why do I bring this up if you're not asking about it? A resume should *POP*. It should be fast to read, get the stuff that's most important to you/your field out and open and, most importantly, hit any important key words so that HR folks pass it on to the 'interview' pile.

Well ok, duh Nahkki. Right?

My point in this is that GPA should be fast, easily digestible and should NEVER EVER take away from the more valuable portions of your resume. "I got an A and this was the best!" Doesn't read well. It's laden with subcontext even though it may seem straight forward.

You say you 'averaged' an A. Which says that at some level there's a numeric system underlying your GPA. GPA, Grade Point Average, that's pretty much how that works. So you should have a 3.8/4.0 (ow whatever) If you're using a 4.0 scale. This should be reported in the same way you report your 8.5/10.0 .

If, for some reason, your school does not calculate GPA in this way then you can easily calculate your own GPA using the marks you received during your MSc.

Honestly, and this is the US in the field of Computer Science, if I saw that someone said they got an 'A' for their MSc I would be a bit weirded out. That's almost certainly different in different countries and different fields. If that's the case I would recommend editing your question to be a bit more specific to the region/field.

Comment: In many graduate programs of international companies, they ask for "good/outstanding/first-class degrees", without explicitly stating a GPA value, since they want to be open to international applicants with a different grading scheme. Therefore I want to show in my CV that I fulfil this criterion, and this is only possible if you know what the grades mean...

Comment: Concerning the averaging: I got As worth 70 credits, Bs worth 30 and Cs worth 20. I don't think it is a good idea to just convert this to some GPA using a 4.0 scale as there are too many assumptions involved.

Comment: @traindrive: My suggestion is not to scale this to a 4.0 GPA scale but to use a numeric value that shows out of a total, best result numeric value, what your end scores were. GPA literally means 'Grade Point Average' which means I am expecting a pointwise system that I can judge. Your example of 8.5/10 is a perfect example of this, that tells me what you got and what the absolute best possible result you could have gotten was. To be pedantic, if you can't convert your grade to a point average then what you have is not a 'GPA'.